# Replaced wrong car in garage in GTA Online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I was asked to replace a car in order to put another car in my garage. However I thought I would be able to swap the car I wanted in and take out the other car that was already in there so I could bring it to my other garage. Can I get my car back?

Answer (score 2):

No your car is gone. I experienced the same thing and the first answer of this question said to call Rockstar games, which I did. I talked to Bernard and credited $725,000.00 back in to our Maze Bank for whatever we spent on our upgraded Turismo car. He can't give back our Turismo car since our garage is full that's why he offered us a credit.

Answer (score 1):

No, your car is gone. If it would have been transferred to the other garage, the option would have stated "transfer", not "replace".

If there is no more room in your specific garage when you want to store a car there, then you get the option to replace an existing car in the garage. If you "replace" this car, it simply disappears.

To avoid this in the future, transfer the car first. Drive the car out of garage A and into garage B, and it will assign that car to the new garage.

You can swap cars between garages this way as well. Say you have car A in garage A and car B in garage B. If you try to drive car A into garage B and it's full, you'll get the option to transfer a car from garage B to garage A. You can use this to rearrange 2 full garages as well.

To get your old car back, you can try contacting Rockstar support. When GTA Online first came out, I was able to get my Adder replaced from accidentally replacing it.

Answer (score -1):

Save yourself the effort. Here's the response I got from Rockstar:

> Hello Arjan,
>
> Thank you for contacting Rockstar Support.
>
> We understand that it is frustrating to lose your car in such a way, but once again we regret to inform you that the purchases of in-game items are always final, and we are unable to offer refunds.
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience this causes, but please let us know if there is anything else we can assist you with.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Joel T.
>   Rockstar Support
>
> Dr-Boom, Aug 29, 13:35 EDT:
>   Well if there is nothing you can dø then please Update the warning text.. Saying something like this Will permenently destroy this vehicle. Thanks allot, you lost an ambassador
>
> Joel T., Aug 29, 13:19 EDT:
>   Hello Arjan,
>
> Thank you for contacting Rockstar Support.
>
> We regret to inform you that the purchases of in-game items are always final, and we are unable to offer refunds. That included in game decision such as car swapping
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience this causes, but please let us know if there is anything else we can assist you with.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Joel T.
>   Rockstar Support